# Pandas - calculate row value based on previous calculated row value

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most effective way to solve following problem with pandas?:

Let's asume we have following df:

```
        v1    v2   
index
0       1     2     
1       5     6    
2       7     3     
3       9     4       
4       5     1
```

Now we want to calculate a third value (v3) based on following function:

```
if df.v1.shift(1) > df.v3.shift(1):
    df.v3 = max(df.v2, df.v3.shift(1))
else:
    df.v3 = df.v2
```

The desired output should look like:

```
        v1    v2    v3
index
0       1     2     2
1       5     6     6
2       7     3     3
3       9     4     4    
4       5     1     4
```

THX & BR from Vienna

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? Without some domain info, it would seem like a loop is the only way to do this.

Comment: I have to deal with millions of rows, that's why I would prefer a solution without a loop.

Comment: I hope you understood what I said. I cannot know what you're trying to do without you telling me exactly what you're trying to calculate. Is it a formula? Is it a procedure? Does it have a name? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to calculate a financial indicator called "SuperTrend" on price data. Here you can find the details: https://wiki.timetotrade.com/Super_Trend?_ga=2.109382789.1866875945.1514904642-742078085.1514904642

Comment: and for those of you who can code in tradesignals pine editor, that's the pine code for it: 

Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(ATR))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(ATR))

TUp=close[1]>TUp[1]? max(Up,TUp[1]) : Up
TDown=close[1]<TDown[1]? min(Dn,TDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = close > TDown[1] ? 1: close< TUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TUp: TDown

Comment: Are you looking for: `v = df.v2.shift().values; np.where(df.v1.shift() > v, np.where(df.v2 > v, df.v2, v), df.v2)`?

Comment: @Also, test this on your real data and perform a timing comparison with the other answer...

Comment: Why you are comparing `v3` while you haven't even created it yet?

Comment: That's how this indicator works, it's calculation based on it's previous value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following two lines gets to your result:

```
df['v3'] = df['v2']
df['v3'] = df['v3'].where(df['v1'].shift(1)<=df['v3'].shift(1),pd.DataFrame([df['v2'],df['v3'].shift(1)]).max())
```

Comment: I don't think it does. The next value depends on the _previous computed value_. This doesn't take the previous computation into account, if I'm not mistaken. It _may_ work for this data, but I'm not sure it'll work for OP's.

Comment: Provide more data then, as this produces the result that you provided.

Comment: It seems like this is a valid way to solve my problem. I'll test it with real data and accept your answer / provide feedback as soon as I'm done with it.